# I cant enable the button again in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to control the password input. And when it is less than 6 characters , I dissable tthe button and dispay an error mesage...But my problem is that when the password is greater than 6 characters the mesage appears again and the button is still disablet...What can I do?
the function is below..Please help me

```
function passcheck() {
    var pass = document.getElementById('password1');
    var sb = document.getElementById('submit');
    if (pass.value.length < 6) {
        document.getElementById('error').style.display = 'block';
        sb.disabled = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('error').style.display = 'none';
        sb.disabled = false;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="password" name="password1" id="password1"  class="textinput" style="margin-left: 15%;margin-top: -2.5%;width: 30%" onchange="passcheck()">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" onclick="location.href='userlogin.html'" class="button" style=" margin-top: 4%;width: 15%" >
<br>
```

Comment: Is this called using the keyup or onchange of the password1 field or when the user tries to submit?

Comment: yes like i posted above now

Comment: Works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5Zs4N/) both in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

`Disabled` is a property, not an attribute.

Use:

```
.removeAttribute("disabled");
```

Comment: I use this and also when i delete this my code doen not function any more..All the time it gives no erros mesage, and the button is enable all the time

Answer (score 0):

Use **onkeyup** instead of **onchange** for calling **passcheck()**.